# Django Rest Framework Serializer format

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have two serializers: one for the `Restaurant` model, another for the `MainMenu` model:

```
class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant


class MainMenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    restaurant = RestaurantSerializer()

    main_menu_items = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MenuMain
        fields = ('id', 'restaurant', 'main_menu_items')
```

The current output of the MainMenuSerializer is

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "restaurant": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Restaurant A",
            "location": "Street B"
        },
        "main_menu_items": [
            "Fried Rice"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "restaurant": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Restaurant A",
            "location": "Street B",
        },
        "main_menu_items": [
            "Noodles"
        ]
    }
]
```

But I want the RestaurantSerializer to only output once, something like this:

```
[
    {
        "restaurant": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Restaurant A",
            "location": "Street B"
        }
    },
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "main_menu_items": [
                "Fried Rice",
                "Meat Balls"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "main_menu_items": [
                "Noodles"
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

EDIT:
models used

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    location  = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

class MenuMain(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField()
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, related_name='main_menus')

class MenuMainItems(models.Model):
    menu_main = models.ForeignKey(MenuMain, related_name='main_menu_items')
    item = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
```

Comment: Can you add your models as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The more "Django REST" way of doing this is to set up a url node for each restaurant that returns all the menu items in the restaurant.  For instance,

**urls.py**

```
url(r'restaurant-menu/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', MenuItemViewset.as_view())
```

**In your viewset class**

```
class MenuItemViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MainMenuSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        return Restaurant.objects.get(pk=pk).menumain_set.all()[0].menumainitems_set.all()
```

This of course assumes one menu per restaurant.  If there are multiple menus and you want to get all of them, it's probably best practice to break it up into two calls: one for the restaurant's menu, and to get a particular menu's items.  Otherwise too many assumptions are being made about the organization of the data, and that's a rather fragile design pattern.

[Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) to docs on fetching related objects

If you still are intent on getting a response like you originally asked for, you just need to reverse the serializer nesting, i.e. add a menu field to the RestaurantSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the very simplest approach I came with. I know this can be improved.
Please comment if you have any query or improvement suggestion.

```
class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
menu = serializers.SerializerMethodField()



def get_menu(self, obj):

    dict_l = {}
    res = MainMenu.objects.all() # filter as per your requirement
    '''
    flds = MainMenu._meta.local_fields
    for ins in res:
        for f in flds:
            print f.name
    '''
    for ins in res:
        dict_l['id'] = ins.id
        dict_l['name'] = ins.name
        dict_l['restaurant'] = ins.restaurant_id
    # return {1: 1, 2: 2}
    return dict_l

class Meta:
    model = Restaurant
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'menu',)
```